# Expose C-Style Array Member of POD structure pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

How could I define c style array with the following members using pybind11?

```
struct Student
{
    int id;
};

struct ClassRoom
{
    Student students[10];
};
```

I want to use in this way.

```
class_room = pytest.ClassRoom()
class_room.students[2].id = 7
```

I tried to do the following as I want to read and write to the Dtype.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>


PYBIND11_MODULE(pytest, m)
{ 
 pybind11::class_<ClassRoom>(m,"ClassRoom")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("students",&ClassRoom::students);
}
```

Comment: Have you found solution? I am having the same problem and somehow pybind documentation is not very strong describing this.

Comment: @Valeria (and OP) is solution involving `std::array` sufficient? With modern C++, `std::array` is preferred over C-style array.

Comment: @TooTone I will try to test it over weekend. In the meantime I ended up making it work by creating a wrapper of ClassRoom which then indeed uses std::array/std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

The road well-trodden is to use `std::vector` rather than an array. This is documented under [STL containers](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html). Here `ClassRoom` would become:

```
struct ClassRoom
{
    std::vector<Student> students = std::vector<Student>(10);
};
```

The only subtlety is that by default pybind uses value semantics. I.e. when you go from C++ to Python, a Python list is created that has a *copy* of the C++ objects (this is covered [later](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types) in the same documentation). What this means here is that `class_room.students[2].id = 7` would have no noticeable effect.

To get reference rather than value semantics, first of all, turn off the pybind copying using the macro `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE`, after which pybind doesn't know anything about `std::vector<Student>`. Second, define a `pybind11::class_` for `std::vector<Student>`. You could do this manually yourself in the same way you define Python classes for `Student` and `ClassRoom`, but fortunately, you don't have to -- pybind11 helpfully provides the implementation for you, in the function `bind_vector` (again, this is covered [later](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers) in the documentation).

The overall code looks like this:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <vector>

// struct Student and struct ClassRoom

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<Student>);

PYBIND11_MODULE(PYMODULE, m)
{
    pybind11::bind_vector<std::vector<Student>>(m, "VectorStudent");

    pybind11::class_<Student>(m, "Student")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("id", &Student::id);
    pybind11::class_<ClassRoom>(m, "ClassRoom")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("students", &ClassRoom::students);
}
```

To be honest, the inefficiency of having a dynamic vector rather than a fixed-size C array on the C++ side, is insignificant compared to the cost of translating between C++ and Python, and the cost of using Python itself. Not only are C arrays pre C++ (and of course pre C++11 upon which pybind11 is based), but also automatically dealing with them would provide little benefit for the implementation required, so it is understandable why they are not supported in pybind11.

Nevertheless, it is possible to translate a C array to Python using pybind11, but it isn't pretty. Essentially, the same approach has to be taken. Pybind11 doesn't define a type for C arrays, so `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE` is unnecessary. What *is* needed is to define a `pybind11::class_` for the C array. The pybind11 function `bind_vector` used above is specific to C++ STL classes, so it's necessary to copy it (from [stl_bind.h](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/stl_bind.h#L491)) and edit it. Taking only the essential functionality gives something like:

```
// Adapt bind_vector from pybind11/stl_bind.h
template <typename T, size_t N, typename... Args>
pybind11::class_<T[N]> bind_array(pybind11::handle scope, std::string const& name, Args&&... args)
{
    using namespace pybind11;
    using Vector = T[N];
    using SizeType = size_t;
    using DiffType = std::ptrdiff_t;

    // Adapted from bind_vector
    using Class_ = class_<Vector>;
    Class_ cl(scope, name.c_str(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // Common code copied from vector_modifiers and vector_accessor
    auto wrap_i = [](DiffType i, SizeType n)
    {
        if (i < 0)
            i += n;
        if (i < 0 || (SizeType)i >= n)
            throw index_error();
        return i;
    };

    // Adapted from vector_modifiers
    cl.def(
        "__setitem__",
        [wrap_i](T& v /* note T[N] has decayed to T* hence T& */, DiffType i, const T& t)
        {
            i = wrap_i(i, N);
            (&v)[(SizeType)i] = t;
        });

    // Adapted from vector_accessor
    cl.def(
        "__getitem__",
        [wrap_i](T& v /* note T[N] has decayed to T* hence T& */, DiffType i) -> T&
        {
            i = wrap_i(i, N);
            return (&v)[(SizeType)i];
        },
        return_value_policy::reference_internal // ref + keepalive
    );

    // Adapted from vector_accessor
    using ItType = T*;
    cl.def(
        "__iter__",
        [](T& v /* note T[N] has decayed to T* hence T& */) {
            return make_iterator<return_value_policy::reference_internal, ItType, ItType, T&>(
                &v, &v + N);
        },
        keep_alive<0, 1>() /* Essential: keep list alive while iterator exists */
    );

    // Adapted from bind_vector
    static_assert(N != 0);
    cl.def(
        "__bool__", []() -> bool { return true; }, "Check whether the list is nonempty");
    cl.def("__len__", []() { return N; });

    return cl;
}
```

This is quite hacky. Notably:

1. Unlike `std::vector<T>` this has to be called multiple times for every `T`, because an array has type `T[N]`, and every `T[N]` with different `N` (for the same `T`) is a separate type.
2. The lambda callbacks take `T&` not `T[N]` because `T[N]` has decayed to `T*` within pybind11. Pybind11 is C++ specific and not intended to handle C arrays, and I'm not 100% confident that there aren't subtle bugs here.

It likely makes sense to nest the type for the array within the containing type (so here you'd have `ClassRoom.Students` on the Python side). Assuming that there are no clashes where an array with the same type `T` is used with the same `N` in different containing structs, it's convenient to define a helper function which both creates the `py::class_` and defines the property.

```
template <typename C, typename T, size_t N, typename... options>
pybind11::class_<C, options...> def_array(
    pybind11::class_<C, options...> class_,
    const char* name,
    T (C::*member)[N],
    const char* type_name = nullptr)
{
    if (type_name == nullptr)
        type_name = name;
    bind_array<T, N>(class_, type_name);
    class_.def_readonly(name, member);
    return class_;
}
```

Usage example

```
    pybind11::class_<ClassRoom> cr(m, "ClassRoom");
    cr.def(pybind11::init<>());
    def_array(cr, "students", &ClassRoom::students, "Students");
```

With this in place, this Python code

```
room = ClassRoom()
print(room)
for i in range(len(room.students)):
    student = Student()
    student.id = i
    room.students[i] = student
print(room)
if room.students:
    print("Not empty")

for student in room.students:
    print("Student", student.id)
```

results in the following output

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Not empty
Student 0
Student 1
Student 2
Student 3
Student 4
Student 5
Student 6
Student 7
Student 8
Student 9
```

Footnote 1: to get `print` working correctly, `__repr__` functions are required. The ones used are shown below (they're rather hacky is it would be better to define `operator<<(ostream&` for `Student` and `ClassRoom` and call those from `__repr__` rather than having `__repr__` write directly) . In any case, the full client code is shown below.

```
struct Student
{
    int id{};
};
struct ClassRoom
{
    Student students[10];
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(PYMODULE, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<Student>(m, "Student")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("id", &Student::id)
        .def("__repr__", [](const Student& obj) { return std::to_string(obj.id); });
    pybind11::class_<ClassRoom> cr(m, "ClassRoom");
    cr.def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def(
            "__repr__",
            [](const ClassRoom& obj)
            {
                std::string repr;
                for (const auto& s : obj.students)
                {
                    repr += std::to_string(s.id);
                    repr += ' ';
                }
                return repr;
            });
    def_array(cr, "students", &ClassRoom::students, "Students");
}
```

Footnote 2: using `std::array` is in general better than using plain old C arrays, where you own the code. Pybind11 provides value-type semantics for `std::arrays`, but doesn't define a binding function. So it's necessary to make the type opaque, but rather than doing it for every `N` using `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE` it's convenient to do it once for all `N` by adapting the macro's implementation. And, again, `bind_vector` can be copied and edited, but this time because `std::array` is an STL type, most of the underlying functions provided by pybind11 can be used as is, so the provided type has much richer functionality (the only function which needs to be modified is `vector_modifiers` but this is a function and can't be partially specialized; hence the whole of `bind_vector` has been copied to change the way `vector_modifiers` works). This code builds and has been tested in simple cases.

```
namespace pybind11::detail
{
template <size_t N>
class type_caster<std::array<Student, N>> : public type_caster_base<std::array<Student, N>>
{
};
} // namespace pybind11::detail

// Adapt bind_vector from pybind11/stl_bind.h
template <typename Vector, typename holder_type = std::unique_ptr<Vector>, typename... Args>
pybind11::class_<Vector, holder_type>
bind_array(pybind11::handle scope, std::string const& name, Args&&... args)
{
    using namespace pybind11;
    using Class_ = class_<Vector, holder_type>;

    // If the value_type is unregistered (e.g. a converting type) or is itself registered
    // module-local then make the vector binding module-local as well:
    using vtype = typename Vector::value_type;
    auto* vtype_info = detail::get_type_info(typeid(vtype));
    bool local = !vtype_info || vtype_info->module_local;

    Class_ cl(scope, name.c_str(), pybind11::module_local(local), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // Declare the buffer interface if a buffer_protocol() is passed in
    detail::vector_buffer<Vector, Class_, Args...>(cl);

    cl.def(init<>());

    // Register copy constructor (if possible)
    detail::vector_if_copy_constructible<Vector, Class_>(cl);

    // Register comparison-related operators and functions (if possible)
    detail::vector_if_equal_operator<Vector, Class_>(cl);

    // Register stream insertion operator (if possible)
    detail::vector_if_insertion_operator<Vector, Class_>(cl, name);

    // Modifiers require copyable vector value type
    // detail::vector_modifiers<Vector, Class_>(cl);

    using SizeType = typename Vector::size_type;
    using DiffType = typename Vector::difference_type;
    auto wrap_i = [](DiffType i, SizeType n)
    {
        if (i < 0)
        {
            i += n;
        }
        if (i < 0 || (SizeType)i >= n)
        {
            throw index_error();
        }
        return i;
    };

    using T = vtype;
    cl.def(
        "__setitem__",
        [wrap_i](Vector& v, DiffType i, const T& t)
        {
            i = wrap_i(i, v.size());
            v[(SizeType)i] = t;
        });

    // Accessor and iterator; return by value if copyable, otherwise we return by ref + keep-alive
    detail::vector_accessor<Vector, Class_>(cl);

    cl.def(
        "__bool__",
        [](const Vector& v) -> bool { return !v.empty(); },
        "Check whether the list is nonempty");

    cl.def("__len__", &Vector::size);

    return cl;
}
```

(An equivalent of `def_array` could be provided if required.)

Answer (score 0):

C-style arrays seems to be not straightforward in PyBind - nevertheless, assuming numpy is available, I'd guess something along the lines of:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(pytest, m)
{ 
   pybind11::class_<ClassRoom>(m,"ClassRoom")
   .def(pybind11::init<>())
   .def_property("students", [](ClassRoom &c) -> pybind11::array {
     auto dtype = pybind11::dtype(pybind11::format_descriptor<Student>::format());
     auto base = pybind11::array(dtype, {10}, {sizeof(Student)});
     return pybind11::array(dtype, {10}, {sizeof(Student)}, c.students, base);
   }, [](ClassRoom& c) {});
}
```

should work, assuming `Student` is defined well in pybind.